# np.random.choice not returning correct weights when vectorized

Tags: python, random, lambda

Thank you @tdelaney for guiding me with my first post, I had to edit it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# This is a hypothetical line to generate a df with a column similar to the one which I'm having trouble with:
dataset_2021 = pd.DataFrame({"genero_usuario":["M", "M", None, "F", None, "F", "M", None, "M", "M", None, "F", "F", "M", None, "M", "M", None, "F", None, "F", "M", None, "M", "M", None, "F", "F", "M", None, "M", "M", None, "F", None, "F", "M", None, "M", "M", None, "F", "F", "M", None, "M", "M", None, "F", None, "F", "M", None]})
```

The dataset has a string column with the user's gender: "M" for Male and "F" for Female, with a few nulls I want to impute. I obtained the weights of "M" and "F" with a value_counts() of the non nulls: M = 0.656, F = 0.344 (this is from my dataset, the test one I wrote up gives 0.6 and 0.4)

The following line of code works perfectly and returns the correct weights when having a big enough dataset (in the small test dataset given above it changes it a little). The problem is that, because of the size of my df, it takes too long to execute:

```
dataset_2021["genero_usuario"] = dataset_2021["genero_usuario"].apply(lambda x : x if pd.isnull(x) == False else np.random.choice(a = ["M","F"], p=[0.656,0.344]))
```

The faster vectorized version I want to use doesn't work. 1st attempt:

```
dataset_2021.loc[dataset_2021.genero_usuario.isnull(), dataset_2021.genero_usuario] = np.random.choice(a = ["M","F"], p=[0.656,0.344])
```

This throws the error:

```
Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values
```

Second attempt:

```
dataset_2021.fillna(value = {"genero_usuario" : np.random.choice(a = ["M","F"], p=[0.656,0.344])}, inplace = True)
```

This imputes the nulls but decreases the weight of the "M" and increases the weight of the "F": the value_counts() gives M 0.616 and F 0.384.

1. Why does the 1st attempt throw that error?
2. Why does the 2nd attempt change the final weights? with lambda it remains equal
3. How can I solve it? I don't want to use lambda, I want the code to remain speedy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please make this a working example including an initialized dataset. It doesn't have to be your real data, just a simple something that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry: this is my first question, I created my account 40 minutes ago. How can I supply an initialized dataset?

Comment: That's close, but its still not something we can execute. We need sample data, and it can be really silly data. We only care about 1 column, so that's all the data should be. Maybe `dataset_2021 = pd.DataFrame({"genero_usuario":["M", "m", None, "F", None, "F", "F", None]})`. Now we can all work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.random.choice` returns one value, so you assign the same value to all null-cells.

Therefore, you have first to find all null-values and generate enough random values to fill all gaps:

```
mask = dataset_2021["genero_usuario"].isnull()
dataset_2021["genero_usuario"][mask] = np.random.choice(size=mask.sum(), a=["M", "F"], p=[0.716, 0.284])
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. That line outputs: "ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable"

Also, I've edited my post by changing the year and adding another attempt that I had tried in that one (I thought it might be relevant.)

Comment: @AgustínBulzomi - you complain that the code doesn't work... but you don't supply working code in your question. If you don't supply testable code you end up with untested answers.

Comment: I'm sorry: this is my first question, I created my account 40 minutes ago. How can I supply the working code?

Comment: @AgustínBulzomi. i don't know what `dataset_2021` is. Pandas? Then a few lines: `import pandas as pd`, `import numpy as np` and `dataset_2021 = pd.DataFrame({"genero_usuario":[1, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 3, np.nan]{)` would do. You may want to fiddle with those initialization values to get something you want.

Comment: Thank you @tdelaney I've just edit it. Hope it suffises; if not, I would appreciate your input :)

Comment: @AgustínBulzomi: answer updated to comply with your new code.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

The code provided threw the infamous view vs copy error, so I made a tiny change by adding the .loc and changing the slicing format in the left side of the equation:

`dataset_2021.loc[dataset_2021["genero_usuario"].isnull(), "genero_usuario"] = np.random.choice(size=dataset_2021["genero_usuario"].isnull().sum(), a=["M", "F"], p=[0.656, 0.344])`

Have a wonderful day Daniel!